# Airflow resource pool usage on DAG-level?

Tags: airflow

I'm looking at using airflow for scheduling test-cases execution against shared hw in a lab and have some best practice questions on how to use the resource pool concept for a whole DAG-instance instead of just on task level.

Basically a test-case needs (executed as a instance of a test-case DAG (deploy/execute/collect/un-deploy)) certain physical resources and should therefore request them from the different resource pools(modelling the the physical resources) in order to not run into conflicting concurrent usage with other triggered DAG-instances.

My question is if it's possible to define resource usage on DAG-instance level or if it's only possible on task level. If the latter, then would one parallel task claiming the resource during the whole DAG-instance execution be the best way to handle not having to pass the resource claim between all tasks in the DAG? Other alternatives?

**Update after questions from Viraj and dlamblin:**
Running 1.10.1

Running LocalExecutor

Have verified that I can run parallel DAGS with concurrent tasks

The resources I want to have custom pools for are not worker resources, rather different peripheral hw units such as relays, routers etc that the tasks running in parallel on a the localexecutor should block on if they are occupied(0 custom resource pool instances left) by an/-other task(s)

Comment: Which version of Airfllow are you running? And how are you running it (e.g. on EC2s, on Kubernetes).

Answer (score 0):

The Kubernetes Executor allows for certain node type affinity to be configured on the task or dag level. The Celery Executor has a queue concept to select from a worker group with certain resources available to the worker. You're probably not using a Local Executor as your question doesn't quite make sense for that case.

Comment: Updating question with details.
Can you explain why you don't think it makes sense for local executor? There might be something I need to clarify.